# Regex for removing everything after a certain character only if the character occurs after a specific number of characters

Tags: regex, string, character

I'm looking for a simple regular expression for this,

Example 1:

```
n = 5

Input: abcde@varun@gmail.com

Output: abcde@varun
```

Example 2:

```
n = 5

Input: abcd@varun@gmail.com

Output: abcd@varun@gmail.com
```

This means that if n = 5 and if the symbol **@** is **NOT** occuring on or before the 5th index(Assuming the string starts at index 1) then remove all everything(including the @ symbol) after the second occurance of **@**.

Leave the string as it is if the above rule is not satisfied.

Thanks Varun.

Comment: Have you tried to solve it? Also specify your language/tool

Comment: Split on `@` then if the first element length is more than 4, just join the first two element, else do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the part that you wish to keep into the first group:

```
(^[^@]{5,}@[^@]*)@
```

The expression matches a string that has at least two `@` signs, with the first `@` not occurring within the initial five characters.

This would capture `abcde@varun`, but not `abcd@varun`, because `@` occurs within the initial five characters.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/mz5Ouq)

Replace `5` with `n` to change the length of the prefix as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:@|.@|.{2}@|.{3}@|.{4}@))(.*?@.*?)@.*$
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uC8uO6/7